# iPhone app not making file in device but works in simulator

Tags: iphone, file, ios-simulator, plist

I have an app and it stores data to a `.plist` file in the resources group in Xcode (if that matters).  And whenever I run it on the simulator it works perfectly with the file.  On the iPhone, however, it doesn't seem to be interacting with the file.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's important to know that the simulator is *not* an emulator, and so the fact that something works in the simulator does not imply that it will work on a real device. For the simulator, your app is compiled for x86, linked against iPhone compatibility libraries, and runs directly on OS X. It's very different than building for and running on a device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to get Documents directory path, you should write any user data there:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot write to the application bundle on the device. It is read-only. You have to write your file to your app's Documents folder.

Comment: I think this is your problem. When you try to write to a file within your app bundle, simulator allows you. After all, it's not a "emulator" that exactly emulates what you get on iPhone. However, trying to write to the same file on iPhone OS will fail.